# SQL Server building the basis for a decision tree

Tags: sql-server, decision-tree

I want to build the data basis for what could be a decision tree. The data I have is the following:

```
|Customer ID| Previous product| New product | Date |
```

I want to represent this so that I can drill down to analyze which product paths our customer take, for example product A -> product B -> product C, or maybe is it most common to go from product B -> product C -> product A.

I was thinking on making a column for each of the 5 latest products, however I am unsure if this is the best way of doing this. How can I represent this

Comment: You aren't describing a decision tree, you are describing a path. You are looking for path calculations, not decisions.

Comment: That's a broad subject. You need an entire article (or book) to describe how to represent a graph in a relational database, and how to accelerate path queries. Joe Celko wrote [a book about this](https://www.elsevier.com/books/joe-celkos-trees-and-hierarchies-in-sql-for-smarties/celko/978-0-12-387733-8)  several years ago. The [T-SQL Querying](https://www.amazon.com/T-SQL-Querying-Developer-Reference-Ben-Gan/dp/0735685045) book covers recursive queries, graphs and hierarchies in its last chapter. The *next* version of SQL Server, 2017, will support graphs at some level.

Comment: *Your* question isn't just "how do I represent a graph". You are trying to find the most common sub-paths. That means, you need to find all subpaths, count them and find the most common